US B1/B2 Visa application: spouse surname in her passport is different from the name in my passport
I am applying for a US B1/B2 Visa for myself. In my passport my spouse's name is different than in her passport. My wife recently changed her name back to maiden name legally but in my passport her name is mentioned with my surname.
Which name should I mention in my US Visa application?

Do your wife also require a visa? Do you travel together?
The question in application is about her (official) name, not about the name on your passport, so I would put that.
But if you are travelling together, and it is not 100% clear that both names refer to the same person, I would add a note. Note: visa officers which handle your application live probably in your country, so they should be familiar to name changes and passports of your country. If you are applying from a different country, add a note.
Worst case: they will ask you during visa appointment.

Thank you for your reply. I am applying visa for myself and traveling alone.
